Unable to access endpoints and keys for importing project in Azure Language Studio
After deploying ARM Templates into an Azure resource group and running Azure Language Studio, in language studio while importing project, we are getting an error

no endpoint keys found

even though we have resource level key available in language studio is active.
We added .env file in in repo, this .env file includes resource level endpoint keys but again getting same error

no endpoint keys found

